# Infinite Stairs Design

Tags: unity, c#

In Unity, I'm trying to create a **puzzle** in a **2D platformer** game where the **player** has to face some **infinite stairs**. The **player** can move **left**, **right** and **jump**.

The idea is that at some point the player encounters some stairs that they try to climb. They climb, and climb, and climb and soon realize there is no end to them. At whatever point they decide to go back down the stairs they realize there are only a couple of them till they found themselves where they started.

Does anyone have any rough idea how something like this can be done?

[image]

Comment: [In 3D games this is often accomplished by building multiple parts of the environment that look identical, and seamlessly teleporting the player from one to an exactly matching position in the other when they cross a trigger threshold](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129677/39518). You should be able to do the same in 2D, if I'm interpreting your storyboard accurately. The details will depend on some particulars of how your game is implemented. Can you take a stab at it based on the linked answer, and edit your question to give us more detail about a specific part you need help with?

Comment: What about once they lose sight of the door they are stuck with infinity in *both* directions with some clear visual indication of what happened (maybe a full screen special effect to cue the player they just entered an “infinity-trap”?), and then they have to find a way to escape—some kind of portal or something else? Personally if I could just walk back to the left and leave it would feel like walking the wrong way up an escalator not an infinite staircase—unless the former is your intent?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create two prefabs: "stairs" and "stairs with bottom and door". Both prefabs should be larger than a whole screen.
2. Create a scene with one instance of the "stairs with bottom and door" prefab and a "stairs" prefab ahead.
3. Whenever the player moves up, `Instantiate` a new stairs prefab ahead of them and `Destroy` the prefab below them.
4. When the player moves down, `Destroy` the prefab ahead of them and `Instantiate` the "stairs with bottom and door" prefab below them.

Comment: Note that if you never teleport the player character, it can be difficult to reconnect with other content in the level - everything would need to be a module spawned just in time this way. There's also the risk that the player could run so far up these infinite stairs that they get a long way from the origin where floating point precision starts to get thin, causing visible glitching.